# React-native: tvOS How to force a Button to be focused?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tvos, apple-tv

It is possible to force a button to be focused ? I know the user can focused an element but I want to make it programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, with tvOS and react native if you want to force a focusable component to be focus you just need to set hasTVPreferredFocus to true

For example:

```
<TouchableHighlight
    hasTVPreferredFocus={true}
    onPress={() => {}}
>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```